# Macro Issues: Eval of a macro body works, but the macro doesn't

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

Consider the following code snippet:

```
[1]> (defvar *clist* '((2 1 21) ( 3 2 32) (4 3 43)))
*CLIST*
[2]> (eval `(case '1 ,@(mapcar #'rest *clist*)))
21
[3]> (defmacro tester (index clist)
      `(case ,index ,@(mapcar #'rest clist))) 
TESTER
[4]> (tester '1 *clist*)
*** - MAPCAR: A proper list must not end with *CLIST*
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
Break 1 [5]>
```

The code contains the error-message generated.
As one can clearly see, that `eval` of the code that is used as the body
of the macro `tester` , gives a result. But the same code (by replacing
`*clist*` and `'1`, by `clist` and `index` variables.) doesn't work when it's used as a body of the macro.

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact code and messages. As we all know, `comma is illegal outside of backquote`, so your question is lying to us.

Comment: I mistakenly deleted the backquotes. The question now has them. @sds

Comment: Thanks. I fixed formatting for you. Now please re-work your last two paragraphs. Not being a native English speaker, I cannot figure out what you mean there. Note that there is not such thing as `emacs-REPL`.

Comment: By emacs-REPL , I mean emacs' window that is named `*slime-repl sbcl*` (mine works on `sbcl`). The reason I put it here, was that the two editors(or environments maybe?)  (GNU CLISP 2.49 and emacs) were giving different errors.

Comment: The message is from SBCL and the error, although differently worded, is identical. The fact that SBCL is running under Emacs is irrelevant.

Comment: Edited again. @sds Okay, so what's the problem? `*clist*` clearly is a list.

Comment: Please remove all mentions of Emacs. Emacs Lisp is not doing evaluation here, and it is not signaling errors. The error comes from SBCL, please see for yourself at a regular REPL.

Comment: `*clist*` is a `symbol`, its value is a `list`. you are not evaluating it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When testing [backquote](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_df.htm), just print it:

```
> `(case '1 ,@(mapcar #'rest *clist*))
(CASE '1 (1 21) (2 32) (3 43))
```

When testing macros, you do *not* evaluate them (either at REPL or, all
the more so, using [`eval`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eval.htm)
explicitly).

You expand the macro using [`macroexpand`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm)
and examine the code.

E.g.,

```
> (macroexpand-1 '(tester '1 *clist*))
*** - MAPCAR: A proper list must not end with *CLIST*
```

This tells you that `tester` passes the `symbol` `*CLIST*` instead of
its value to `mapcar`.

You need to think what you are trying to do in terms of 
["compile-time"](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_a.htm)
vs ["execution time"](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_b.htm).

- Do you know the `index` at compile time?
- Do you know the `clist` at compile time?

In your case, there is no reason to use `case`:

```
(defmacro tester (index clist) `(third (find ,index ,clist :key #'second)))
(macroexpand-1 '(tester 1 *clist*))
==> (THIRD (FIND 1 *CLIST* :KEY #'SECOND)) ; T
(tester 1 *clist*)
==> 21
```

Since you do not know the *value* of `clist` at compile time (only the
variable name where it is stored), there is
no win in using `case` - it has to know all clauses at compile time.

Comment: Is this occurring due to the fact that macros don't evaluate their arguments, because of which, the macro `tester` didn't evaluate `*clist*`, and just put the symbol `*clist*`, into the expansion?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your macro, remove the expansion and just print its arguments:

```
CL-USER 4 > (defmacro tester (index clist)
              (print (list :macro-tester :index index :clist clist))
              nil)
TESTER
```

Now we call it with your example:

```
CL-USER 5 > (tester 1 *clist*)

(:MACRO-TESTER :INDEX 1 :CLIST *CLIST*) 
NIL
```

So `index` is `1` and `clist` is the symbol `*clist*`.

Now let's try to call `mapcar` with the function `rest` and the symbol `*clist*`:

```
CL-USER 9 > (mapcar #'rest '*clist*)

Error: *CLIST* (of type SYMBOL) is not of type LIST.
  1 (abort) Return to level 0.
  2 Return to top loop level 0.
```

That's the error you are seeing. The symbol `*clist*` is not a valid list.